# HTTP 1.1 Content-MD5 redundancy given TCP/IP Checksum?

Tags: linux, apache, http, networking, tcp

I was just wondering, in the HTTP 1.1 specifications, there is a field Content-MD5. However, since HTTP ride atop TCP/IP in the entire OSI Stack, and given that TCP/IP has a Header Checksum to ensure that all data transmitted is checked, I am curious as to why the need for a Content-MD5 in the HTTP 1.1 specifications? Did I misunderstand or miss out something?

For the HTTP/1.1 header specs I referred to:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.15

For the TCP/IP specs I referred to section 3.1 at:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc791.txt

To me, by adding the Content-MD5 in the HTTP header, we're just adding more work to be done at the server. Why not just use the mechanisms that TCP/IP already provides?

Cheers and thanks to all in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HTTP content MD5 value is independently useful.

The TCP checksum is pretty weak, and given the amount of data transmitted on the Internet, it is quite likely that there are silent failures of the TCP checksum value.

If you really care, however, you want to use something stronger, like TLS.

Comment: One example; if you are a proxy or cache and want to verify a file that you have stored locally is valid, issuing a HEAD request for the resource to get the server's MD5 for the file will tell you if you have the same version.

Comment: TCP checksum doesn't protect from protocol/application errors.  For example, if the file is being transmitted as chunked and the chunks are correct, that doesn't mean the content is correct, but the TCP checksums are correct.  Some servers are set up to not report errors, so the web application just stops and the clients gets whatever it stopped on.  So the protocol fails because there is no integrity check of that content.

Comment: It's possible to download an OS iso file (i.e. huge file) where you may experience collision on a single tcp segment, hence venders tend to include sha-1 hashes so you can manually verify after the fact. Wouldn't it be nice if the browser did this for you?

Additionally http can be sent over UDP (and is for many services other than www)

Answer (score 4):

I would assume it's to help the client determine if a proxy server scrambled the content in transit. You could still have valid TCP packets but invalid content.

Comment: From what I understand, a client that makes a request through a proxy servers that acts as a cache will require the client to establish a TCP/IP connection with the proxy server. When that is done, the packet will travel up to the Application Layer of the proxy server for the proxy server to process the request. This means that if the proxy server had changed the http content, it would have recomputed the http content-md5 and the TCP checksum will be recomputed before sending as well as the IP header being recomputed from node to node. up vote for the proxy server point (:

Comment: @Vern you are describing *correct* proxy server behavior. Very easy to imagine a proxy which attempts to perform content modification and does not take the time to re-compute the header fields correctly.